# Using the include function in template down the directory

Tags: php, relationship

I wish to use header (includes css, js and images) and footer files located in a folder called /template. These files then get included in every file down the directory for example:

```
/template/header.php + footer.php
/home/index.php
/products/products.php
/products/hardware/types/hardware.php
/css
/js
/images
```

When i use:

```
include (__DIR__ . "/../template/header.php");
```

The file is included (although i need to change each file and ad more "/../" the further down the directory i go) but all the css, js and images are broken.

here is my header (located in header.php, one of the included files):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/layout.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/slider.css"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/menus.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/forms.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/control.js"></script>

<title>APEC Energy - <?php echo($PageTitle);?> </title>
</head>
```

I am now trying to use a config file (which is hard to get working and still doesnt for me).

config.php (placed in root folder):

```
<?php

$paths = array(
    "root" => "./",
        "controller"    => "controller",              
        "stylesheets"   => "css",
        "images"        => array(...),
        "javascript"    => array(...),

);

$projectName = "/";
function fInc($filePath){
    global $projectName;
    return '//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$projectName.'/'.$filePath;
}

?>
```

and in each .php file calling for the including file im using:

```
<?php
$rootDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".(explode ('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])[1]);
require_once($paths['helper']['html']."template/header.php");
?>
```

When i use var_dump($paths), it prints out "NULL"

but just get a blank screen now?

Comment: What is the return value of $paths['helper']['html']?

Comment: unsure what the value is. Was advised this statement would fix it. tried a few statements to link in the required file but unsuccessful.

Comment: Then just do a var_dump() of $paths and edit it into your question

Comment: I have put all code that i am using in the config.php file above. I think i need to include more directory and files in the array but not sure how to.

Comment: Just do a `var_dump($paths)` instead of `require once....` at the end of the .php file, that will print the value of the variable on the screen. Copy it and edit it into your question please.

Comment: Ok done, it prints out none "NULL"

Comment: So, if there are no value, you should check, when you fill your array.

Comment: @david that's at least the answer why there's a white sreen. Because you're including nothing `NULL`. Are you including the `config.php` file in your scripts?

Comment: no , only what you see above. thought php looks up the config.php automatically wherever you place it? also dont think i am entering enough information into the array in the config.php file. do i need to include paths for each file? or each directory in the array? if so can you show me how. day 4 trying to make this work.

Comment: have entered ` <?php
$PageTitle = "Building Services";
$rootDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".(explode ('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])[1]);
require_once($rootDir . "/config.php");
require_once($paths['helper']['html']."/template/header.php");
?> `

Answer (score 0):

In the header, all of your URLs are relative. For me, this often leads to unexpected behavior when including it in PHP-files in different folders, even though the output file is always in the same folder. In order to save myself from the problems of relative URLs, I always use absolute URLs no matter what I'm referencing or where I'm doing it.

To get the root URL for my project, I use the following code:

```
rtrim('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], substr(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'), 1))
```

The settings file would look something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace;

class Settings
{

    /**
     * Main settings for the system.
     *
     * All system-wide non-specific settings goes here.
     *
     * @param string $setting Name of the setting you want to return.
     * @return string Returns the specified setting value or, if this fails, false.
     */
    public static function main($requested)
    {
        $settings = array(
            'base_url' => rtrim('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], substr(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'), 1)),
            'site_title' => 'My Awesome Site',
            'debug_on' => true,
            'some_other_setting' => 'some value',
        );
    }
}
```

To use a setting, I include the file and use a static call to get my setting. Like this:

```
Settings::main('base_url')
```

The result is the root folder of the script served to the browser. I always make sure to use `index.php` in my root folder as a single point of entry so I'm always sure the code returns the root folder. From there it's a simple matter of adding whatever path you need to your resources.

Comment: the settings file, is this a separate file like "config.php"? how would i call the required file to be included? do i need to adjust the ccs js and image links? not sure how to implement your suggestion

Comment: Yes, it's a separate file. I use a class autoloader to include it, but you can also use `require_once` or any other way of including an external PHP file. If you're not using namespaces, simply delete that line from the top and you should be good to go.

Comment: ok great will give it a try now, whats namespaces? once i load the file i can use `code <?php Settings::main('base_url'); ?>`

Comment: i did the following on the page calling for an include: `code <?php
$PageTitle = "Building Services";
rtrim('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], substr(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'), 1));
include (__DIR__ . "/settings.php");
Settings::main('base_url');
?>`

Comment: testing locally is that ok? still blank screen

Comment: `Settings::main('base_url');` only returns the value. You have to use `echo` to actually make it display. `echo Settings::main('base_url');` should display the path.

Comment: Namespaces separates code. If you make a project you will use your own, unique class names, right? Then you might decide to add code that someone else has created. If that code uses classes with the same names as your own code, you'll have a conflict. Namespaces resolve conflicts like that. You can think about them as virtual folders. Each folder can only have files with unique names, but the same file can be placed in many different folders.

Comment: `code <?php
$PageTitle = "Building Services";
rtrim('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], substr(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'), 1));
include (/settings.php);
echo Settings::main('base_url');
require_once($paths['helper']['html']."/template/header.php");
?> `

Comment: still get a white screen